# iOS 5: How do I link a UITableView from Storyboard to a custom subclass UIViewTableController?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I've created a Custom Table View Controller in Xcode 4.2 and I've created a UITableView inside of a view in Storyboard. How do I link the UITableView (which doesn't appear in my code) to my Custom View Controller?(which is a subclass of UITableViewController)

Comment: It would be easier to just have 2 UITableViews in a UIViewController

Comment: When you subclass `UITableViewController`, you automatically get a `tableView` inside the `UITableViewController` (e.g. `tableViewController.tableView`). Why are you creating another instance of `UITableView`? If you really need two seperate `UITableView`'s you may want to consider another design/approach.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to nest a UITableView within a View, but I want to have access to it in the code. When I create it in Storyboard, no new files are created in the project to my knowledge. Thus, I thought that I had to create a subclass of UITableViewController. How can I accomplish what I want to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Drag an instance of `UITableViewController` from inspector to the stage in IB, storyboard.
2. Cmd+N and from templates, choose either an instance of `NSObject` class or `UITableViewController`.
3. If you chose `NSObject` in step 2, make sure to change `NSObject` to `UITableViewController` in the header file.
4. Save it as let's say `CustomTableViewController`.
5. In IB, set the class of `UITableViewController` as `CustomTableViewController`.
6. In implementation of `CustomTableViewController`, you can get a pointer to the `tableView` by calling `self.tableView`.

Let me if any part is not clear.